# Local background image not displaying in html

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am trying to get background images working for html output from a system I develop for. I can output the page correctly, but the background images do not correctly display when referencing a file on the local machine; however if I reference the same image from an external site it works correctly.

I have the html file saved at `<USER_DOCUMENTS>\Test_HTML.html` and the example local image saved at `<USER_DOCUMENTS>\images\test_image.png`. The image I am using for the example is [this](http://www.bilingo.co.za/wp-content/themes/bilingo-01/images/logo_symbol.png), but any suitable image that can be externally referenced should suffice.

**Test_HTML.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         td{font-family:arial; font-size:12pt; border:solid black 1pt;}
         .test_class{background-image:url(images\test_image.png); background-repeat:repeat; background-position:top left;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="test_class" style="width:40pt">Baap</td>
         <td class="test_class" style="width:60pt">Beep</td>
         <td class="test_class" style="width:80pt">Biip</td>
         <td class="test_class" style="width:100pt">Boop</td>
         <td class="test_class" style="width:120pt">Buup</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <hr/>
   <img src="images\test_image.png"/>
</html>
```

When viewing this in a browser (tested in Chrome, Firefox & IE), the image below the horizontal rule displays correctly, but there is no background displayed in the table. However if `url(images\test_image.png)` is replaced with `url(<EXTERNAL_FILE_LOCATION>)` then the background images display correctly. The desired behaviour is to be able to use the local file and get the same output as when using an external file location.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to get this to work correctly on the local system, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The url should be given of the format url("./images/test_image.png"); or url("images/test_image.png"); You shouldn't use backslashes while passing a location like the windows standard. You need to use forward slashes "/".

Comment: your slashes are the wrong way round you need to give the url relative to the url of the file that is requesting the image (not the relative filepath). I think image tags are a bit more forgiving with the direction of slashes than css

Comment: This worked, thanks. If one of you two would like to write this up as an answer then I'd like to accept that as you were the first to give the correct solution. Also any insight into why this works with the `<img>` tag and not for background images would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like, I mentioned in my comment above, "\" or backslash is generally used for referring to the absolute path of a path and is a Windows standard for referring to the location of files. 
We make use of "/" or forward slashes as they are used to refer to the relative path with the current working file. So,

`./` refers to the current working directory.

`../` refers to the parent directory.

`./images/` refers to a folder which is present in the same location as the working directory and likewise to access the files inside the folder, you put a forward slash to refer to it.

As for, why it worked when you used the backslash path inside the img tag but not in the css, I'm not really sure of. But it's not a good practice and definitely not the proper way of doing things. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the write up. I really dislike how Windows uses backslashes for file separators where everywhere else uses forward slashes and backslashes for escaped characters; as once again it has risen up to hamper my development efforts.

Comment: Well, on researching about it I found out that when Microsoft released their MS-DOS O/S, they use the "/" as a “switch” character. You can still see this today in the command prompt — running the command dir /w tells the dir command to run with the wide list format option, while running the command dir c:\ tells the dir command to list the contents of drive C:\. So, they can't just re-use it and "/" was the most visually similiar character they could then make use for seperating directories.

Comment: Huh, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the slash '\' to '/'. URL's have to be in forward slash